# How can I check if a code block is optimized away, without looking at the compiled code?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

How can I check if a code block is optimized away, without looking at the compiled code?

E.g.:

```
void Func(const int val) {
    const int minVal = 100;
    if(val > minVal) {
        // Complex code block
    }
}
...
Func(200);
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    Func(50);
```

How can I check that `Func(50)`, and the entire `for` loop, is optimized away?
In this case, the compiler should have all the elements to take such a decision.

Comment: An optimization is only allowed if it doesn't impact the observable behaviour of the program, so if you write your code in any way that you could observe if the code is optimized out then it won't be.

Comment: it depends on the compiler itself so u have to check what the compiler generates or use a tool that checks what the compiler generates.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Does it mean that in this case I can be certain the optimization will take place?

Comment: Read the assembly code anyway. "Maybe the compiler does this, since it is allowed to" isn't any sort of guarantee, who would be satisfied with that?

Comment: @asmmo - Could you suggest such a tool? (possibly for Linux)

Comment: Apparently [GCC does optimize this in at least the specific case I tested](https://godbolt.org/z/G8T38GPGx), which may or may not generalize to your real-life code (E: so to clarify, we can see there that GCC only (tail-)calls `foo` once and doesn't loop at all)

Comment: _"...I can be certain the optimization..."_ no it mean you need to look at the generated assembly.  Any change you make to the program that __could__ allow you to observe that the code is optimized out, will stop the code from being optimized out, as the compiler would now be making an observable change to the program.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Some non-behavior stuff are observable, as time of execution ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be answered in a generalized manner. It will depend on a variety of factors. Results vary between compilers, and whether or not the code will be optimized out will depend on the level of optimization.

An unoptimized build (ie. O0) will more than likely keep the check, as those will usually not even inline anything to make debugging easier (thus, it can never know what value "val" has.

Optimized builds can and optimize this situation, with one catch: The compiler needs to actually be able to see the functions definition (not declaration) in the translation-unit. If you declare "func" in a header, define it's implementation in a cpp-file, and use "func" in another cpp-file, it won't be able to optimize it, unless some kind of link-time code generation is used.
Furthermore, the compilers evaluation must determine that "func" is actually something worth inlining. This will be likely for a small function, but for larger ones, it becomes less likely. There are hints and instructions for the compiler to inline certain functions, but those should almost never be used.

But since we are in C++, let's answer one more question: What if you actually need to ensure that the block is optimize away, maybe even in debug-builds? Well, we can do this, though it has downsides:

```
template<int Val>
void Func() {
    static constexpr int minVal = 100;
    if constexpr(Val > minVal) {
        // Complex code block
    }
}

func<200>();
```

Using non-type template parameters, you can actually specify a compile-time constant parameter to the function. Changing "minVal" to an actual constexpr constant, we can use "if constexpr" to force the compiler to do this check at compile-time (at least if you have access to c++17).
Now I'm not saying you should do this - it has obvious downsides. Now "Val" must actually be a constant parameter, for once. Also, it will force multiple instantiations of the same function, for every "Val" that is passed in, in every compilation-unit. It can have a negative impact on compile-time. But it's an option, if your use-case for whatever reason requires it. Though in practise, if constexpr is something that you mostly use in meta-programming contexts where you are already inside a template-function.